# Is there any way to make Salesforce UI more interactive?

Tags: visualforce

Is there any way to make Salesforce UI more interactive like the "walkme" app? I wanted to add a modal window to change the theme and font. I added a colourpicker to a standard UI page. It does changes the color but I'm unable to save the changes.
Here's the screenshot ..

[image: color picker for standard UI]

Here's the code

```
<apex:page >
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.colorbox, 'jscolor/jscolor.js')}" />
 <p> Change background: <input class="color"
  onchange="test(this.color);document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color"/></p>

   <script>
    function test(x)
    {
         document.getElementById('AppBodyHeader').style.backgroundColor = '#'+x;
         document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+x;

    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Please suggest me if I'm going the right way.

Comment: screenshot not clear

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8951q8j144vw9m/color.png. Here's the link @Mohith Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to save the data to a custom object.  Right now, your code is simply part of the view-state only.  Add this to your javascript:

```
var theme = new sforce.SObject("My_Custom_Object__c");
theme.My_Theme_Color__c = '#'+x;
result = sforce.connection.upsert([theme]);
if (!result[0].getBoolean("success")) alert('Failed to save your theme ' + result[0]);
```

You can then work on something to populate onload from `My_Custom_Object__c`

Comment: I tried the code. But unable to save the color.

Comment: I pasted this rather hastily, it should have been "upsert" instead of "update"... You should also have a conditional property that "gets" the current Id if they've already saved one so that it updates instead of inserts a new one...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how you'd expect to save the changes for this — you can't write to Salesforce's CSS file and short of some hacks which involve putting HTML into the sidebar you're probably not likely to find a clean solution, if any such thing exists.

I'd advise against trying to make frivolous changes like this as they're only likely to break further down the line when Salesforce release updates. Customer communities can be coloured, perhaps this functionality will come to the rest of the CRM later on.

Comment: Thanks @LaceySnr. I tried that too but then the changes wont be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want true customizability I recommend just creating an external app that uses the salesforce API.

Comment: Thnx Ethan. I was wondering if I could make some changes in the Std UI itself.

Comment: @MnZ for some of the standard UI you can integrate canvas applications in various places which would allow you some non standard functionality in the standard ui.

Comment: I looked into canvas apps. Pretty cool feature. But will it allow me to insert/update fields in salesforce if I interact with a canvas app?

Comment: @MnZ yes it will. Your canvas app can use the REST/SOAP Salesforce APIs to update your salesforce data.